# Come vs walk into one's room

Tags: verbs

Do the following sentences mean the same? which one doesn't sound natural:

> - Please don’t **walk** into my room without knocking.
> - Please don’t **come** into my room without knocking.

Comment: Another option is "Please don't enter my room without knocking."

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine, but **come** feels slightly better as it focuses on the thing that matters (entry to room) and not the walking; we don't want folks leaning in, running in, jumping in ...